# How to search in Firebase Database Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchbar

## am trying to use UISearchbar with my firebase database but i don't know if my code is rghit or not becuase it's crash everytime i run it and this's my code

```
var hotelList = [hotelsModel]()
var hotelsArray : [NSDictionary] = []
var filterHotels : [NSDictionary] = []
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()


databaseRef.child("Hotels").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.hotelsArray.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)

        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.hotelsArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
```

1. List item

   ```
   }) { (error) in
       print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
   ```

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       //creating a cell using the custom class
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! hotelsTableViewCell

   ```
   let hotelSearch : NSDictionary?
   //the artist object
   var hotel: hotelsModel
   //getting the artist of selected position
   //hotel = hotelList[indexPath.row]
   if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {

       hotelSearch = filterHotels[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
   } else {
       //getting the artist of selected position
       hotel = hotelList[indexPath.row]
   }

   //getting the artist of selected position
   hotel = hotelList[indexPath.row]
   //adding values to labels
   cell.lblName.text = hotel.name
   cell.lblLocation.text = hotel.location
   cell.appSuggest.text = hotel.appSuggest
   cell.price.text = hotel.price
   cell.canceletion.text = hotel.cancelation
   cell.paymentNeeded.text = hotel.paymentNeeded

   if let imgUrl = hotel.img{
       let url = URL(string: imgUrl)
       cell.img.kf.setImage(with: url)
       cell.img.clipsToBounds = true
       cell.img.layer.cornerRadius = 10
       cell.img.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
       cell.img.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.8
       cell.img.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 0)
   }
         return cell
   ```

   }
   func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
       //update the searchbar result
       //filterHotels(serachText:searchController.searchBar.text!)
       filterHotels.removeAll()
       filterHotels = hotelsArray.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
           let tmp: NSString = (text as? NSString ?? nil) ?? ""
           let range = tmp.range(of: searchController.searchBar.text!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
           return range.location != NSNotFound
       })
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

### it's crashed in this line

```
self.hotelsArray.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
```

#### How can I solve this?

#### Thank You